# Convexity and uniqueness in trend filtering with spikes

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am reading a paper$^\color{magenta}{\star}$ on $\ell_{1}$ trend filtering. In the conclusion, there is an optimization problem I am trying to solve. Assume we have data $y\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and we solve the following optimization problem

$$ (x,u) := \arg \min \frac12 \| y - x - u \|_{2}^{2} + \lambda \| D x \|_{1} + \rho \|u\|_{1},$$

where $D$ is trend filtering $\mathbb{R}^{(n-2)\times n}$ full row rank matrix. The problem is coercive, but strict convexity is not clear. This is called trend filtering with spikes.

I do not see why this problem is strictly convex, so that it always has a unique solution?

---

<sub>$\color{magenta}{\star}$ Seung-Jean Kim, Kwangmoo Koh, Stephen Boyd, Dimitry Gorinevsky, [$\ell_1$ trend filtering](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/papers/l1_trend_filter.html), SIAM Review, 2009.</sub>

Comment: to me $\ell_{1}$ norma are not a problem. I try to understand why does this problem have a unique solution

Comment: it will be a block diagonal matrix and the determinant will be zero

Comment: Isn't the claim that the **Hodrick–Prescott** filter (without 1-norms) is strictly convex "and so has a unique minimizer"?

Comment: I do not understand, could you, please, clarify? It is from the paper I am referring to.  Hodrick–Prescott filter is strictly convex, but please compare them. We also add one more variable inside the norm in the first term

Comment: What is strictly convex is the HP filter, which only uses 2-norms.  Are you sure your question makes any sense?  Please quote the relevant part of the paper.

Comment: yes, my question does make sense. I do not understand why the problem has a unique solution. Please, look an HP filter and compare it with the one in the question.

Comment: it was a typo, of course it is $\arg \max$. The paragraph is 7.4. Thanks

Comment: Why not copy-paste the paragraph?